# Eclipse showing spaces but "python -tt" claims tab

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have been slowly fixing my Python files for a project by developing everything in Eclipse.  However, I am currently stuck because I get an *`Unexpected Indent Error`*.

I set the preferences to replace tabs with 4 spaces, and I have used search/replace to convert existing tabs into 4 spaces.

The displayed file looks like it has all spaces for indentation, but using `python -tt script.py` claims it is still a tab.  I have repeatedly deleted the characters and replaced with spaces, but it still claims there is a tab on line 358:

```
357>    else:
358>        target1 = 2
```

Comment: Display your file with a filter like `od`, `xxd`, or your favorite hex editor.

Comment: I don't know what I'm looking at when I use those commands...

Comment: Instead of hex, try to `print repr(open('script.py').read())`. Do you get any `'\t'`s?

Comment: When in doubt about what a string contains go with `repr`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do the following to prevent tab characters in the first place

> Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editor -> Insert spaces for tabs = True
>   Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editor -> Displayed Tab Width = 4.

Next, check the following checkbox to view white space characters.

> Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editor -> Show whitespace characters

This will display all the tabs and newline characters in your source file. Once you have modified the first option, format the file (using Ctrl + Shift + F) to replace all tabs with spaces and then you will see the correct indentation.